# Ionic 3 Filter List

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I'm stuck here

When I clicked the list, nothing happens and the console don't show anything. I use the search filter typescript into list filter. I'm not good in ionic especially angular js.

popular.html:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select  (click)="this.filterService.getYear($event)" >
    <ion-option value="first">1st Year</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="second">2nd Year</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="third">3rd Year</ion-option>
    <ion-option valur="fourth">4th Year</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="fifth">5th Year</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

filter.ts:

```
getYear(searchbar, item)
{
    let nav = this.app.getActiveNav();

    console.log(this.posts);

    this.keyboard.close();

    this.initializeItems();

    var q = searchbar.srcElement.value;
    if (!q) {
        return;
    }

    this.filters = this.posts.filter((value) => {

        console.log(value);

        if (value.data().year && q) {
            if (value.data().year.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the ngModel data binding for this, as described in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/)

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
    <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

For your example, this would change to

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]=“filterService.getYear($event)”>
```

Comment: [Angular] Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 16 in [getYear($event)=$event]

Comment: I got it. I used this:
<ion-select  [(ngModel)]="year" (ionChange)="this.filterService.getItems(year)">

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `(ionChange)` instead of `(click)`, like

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="getYear($event)">
```

Or probably `filterService.getYear($event)` in your case, although I am not a big fan of accessing services from the template.

The `getYear` function will be called with the `value` of selected item, ie, "first", "second" etc, and hence should ideally have a single argument, instead of 2.

Example [Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cuycfw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)/[Preview](https://ionic-cuycfw.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thanks, but I think that this typescript of search filter is not applicable to the list filter.